# Unable to remove specific button which have the same classname inside listitems using a queryselector?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, queryselector

In my Incomplete task and complete task : I want when I check my incomplete task to complete task I don't want to show my update button only  Task name and a Delete button will be there, nothing else:
please see on my JS file: an `completeTask()` function to understand the problem more:

HTML:

```
 <p class="text-2xl py-1 font-bold">
                            Incomplete Tasks
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <ul id="items">
                            <li class="py-5 px-2 item"><input type="checkbox" />
                                <label>Task Name</label>
                                <button class="update py-1 ml-12 px-2 text-md text-white rounded  bg-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-600 focus:ring-opacity-50">Update</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="py-5 px-2 item"><input type="checkbox" />
                                <label>Task Name</label>
                                <button class="update py-1 ml-12 px-2 text-md text-white rounded  bg-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-600 focus:ring-opacity-50">Update</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="py-5 px-2 item"><input type="checkbox" />
                                <label>Task Name</label>
                                <button class="update py-1 ml-12 px-2 text-md text-white rounded  bg-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-600 focus:ring-opacity-50">Update</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded">
                    <div>
                        <p class="text-2xl py-1 font-bold">
                            Completed Tasks
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <ul id="items2">
                            <li class="py-5 px-2 item">
                                <label>Task Name</label>
                                <button class="delete py-1 ml-12 px-2 text-md text-white rounded  bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-600 focus:ring-opacity-50">Delete</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

JS file:

```
let completeTask = function(){
    let listItem = this.parentNode;
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'Delete';
    deleteBtn.className = 'delete';
    deleteBtn.style.paddingLeft = '10px';
    listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    
   
    let checkBox = listItem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkBox.remove();
    completeUl.appendChild(listItem);
    
//here my checkbox I successfully remove it, but in the same way when I do for update button it don't work. //  

    bindDeleteItems(listItem,deleteTask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a default class name like "unchecked/not completed". When you select a task, conditionally check is it checked or not. If it is selected then add a class "checked/completed" and hide the updated button by using a hidden tag before the class name.

Answer (score -1):

So, first of all in the "completeTask" function, when you check the checkbox, conditionally add an extra class in the Update button "Completed".

Then again run the querySelector for finding the class "completed". After that remove that button form the ListItems.